# JSON/JQ: Merge 2 files on key-value with condition

Tags: json, bash, shell, merge, jq

I have 2 JSON files. I would like to use jq to take the value of "capital" from File 2 and merge it with File 1 for each element where the same "name"-value pair occurs. Otherwise, the element from File 2 should not occur in the output. If there is no "name"-value pair for an element in File 1, it should have empty text for "capital."

File 1:

```
{
   "countries":[
      {
         "name":"china",
         "continent":"asia"
      },
      {
         "name":"france",
         "continent":"europe"
      }
   ]
}
```

File 2:

```
{
   "countries":[
      {
         "name":"china",
         "capital":"beijing"
      },
      {
         "name":"argentina",
         "capital":"buenos aires"
      }
   ]
}
```

Desired result:

```
{
   "countries":[
      {
         "name":"china",
         "continent":"asia",
         "capital":"beijing"
      },
      {
         "name":"france",
         "continent":"europe",
         "capital":""
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Answer (score 1):

You could first construct a dictionary from File2, and then perform the update, e.g. like so:

```
jq --argfile dict File2.json '
  ($dict.countries | map( {(.name): .capital}) | add) as $capitals
  | .countries |= map( .capital = ($capitals[.name] // ""))
' File2.json
```

From a JSON-esque perspective, it would probably be better to use `null` for missing values; in that case, you could simplify the above by omitting `// ""`.

### Using `INDEX/2`

If your jq has `INDEX/2`, then the $capitals dictionary could be constructed using the expression:

```
INDEX($dict.countries[]; .name) | map_values(.capital)
```

Using INDEX makes the intention clearer, but if efficiency were a major concern, you'd probably be better off using `reduce` explicitly:

```
reduce $dict.countries[] as $c ({}; . + ($c | {(.name): .capital}))
```

Answer (score 0):

One way:

```sh
$ jq --slurpfile file2 file2.json '
   { countries:
      [ .countries[] |
        . as $curr |
        $curr + { capital: (($file2[0].countries[] | select(.name == $curr.name) | .capital) // "") }
      ]
    }' file1.json
{
  "countries": [
    {
      "name": "china",
      "continent": "asia",
      "capital": "beijing"
    },
    {
      "name": "france",
      "continent": "europe",
      "capital": ""
    }
  ]
}
```

An alternative:

```sh
 $ jq -n '{ countries: ([inputs] | map(.countries) | flatten | group_by(.name) |
                        map(select(.[] | has("continent")) | add | .capital //= ""))
          }' file[12].json
```

Comment: You really don't want to use `flatten` or `group_by` here, especially `group_by` as its implementation involves a sort.

Comment: @peak If it does what I need, I'll happily use it.