# jq merge json via dynamic sub keys

Tags: json, bash, jq

I think I'm a step off from figuring out how to jq [reduce](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Reduce) via [filter](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Basicfilters) a key to another objects sub-key.

I'm trying to combine files (simplified from Elasticsearch's [ILM Explain](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-explain-lifecycle.html) & [ILM Policy](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ilm-get-lifecycle.html) API responses):

```sh
$ echo '{".siem-signals-default": {"modified_date": "siem", "version": 1 }, "kibana-event-log-policy": {"modified_date": "kibana", "version": 1 } }' > ip1.json
$ echo '{"indices": {".siem-signals-default-000001": {"action": "complete", "index": ".siem-signals-default-000001", "policy" : ".siem-signals-default"} } }' > ie1.json
```

Such that the resulting JSON is:

```json
{
  ".siem-signals-default-000001": {
    "modified_date": "siem",
    "version": 1
    "action": "complete",
    "index": ".siem-signals-default-000001",
    "policy": ".siem-signals-default"
  }
}
```

Where ie1 is base JSON and for a child-object, its sub-element `policy` should line up to ip1's key and copy its sub-elements into itself. I've been trying to build off [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64809910), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46255183/15146924), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66127460/15146924) (from StackOverflow, also [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/588063/merging-multiple-json-file-into-one-object-using-jq-with-argument), [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/bash/comments/e035cb/is_it_possible_to_use_dynamic_key_in_jq/), [this](https://e.printstacktrace.blog/merging-json-files-recursively-in-the-command-line/) from external sources). I'll list various rabbit hole attempts building off these, but they're all insufficient:

```sh
$ ((cat ie1.json | jq '.indices') && cat ip1.json) | jq -s 'map(to_entries)|flatten|from_entries' | jq '. as $v| reduce keys[] as $k({}; if true then .[$k] += $v[$k] else . end)'
{
  ".siem-signals-default": {
    "modified_date": "siem",
    "version": 1
  },
  ".siem-signals-default-000001": {
    "action": "complete",
    "index": ".siem-signals-default-000001",
    "policy": ".siem-signals-default"
  },
  "kibana-event-log-policy": {
    "modified_date": "kibana",
    "version": 1
  }
}
```

```sh
$ jq --slurpfile ip1 ip1.json '.indices as $ie1|$ie1+{ilm: $ip1 }' ie1.json
{
  ".siem-signals-default-000001": {
    "action": "complete",
    "index": ".siem-signals-default-000001",
    "policy": ".siem-signals-default"
  },
  "ilm": [
    {
      ".siem-signals-default": {
        "modified_date": "siem",
        "version": 1
      },
      "kibana-event-log-policy": {
        "modified_date": "kibana",
        "version": 1
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I also expected something like this to work, but it compile errors

```sh
$ jq -s ip1 ip1.json '. as $ie1|$ie1 + {ilm:(keys[] as $k; $ip1 | select(.policy == $ie1[$k]) | $ie1[$k]  )}' ie1.json
jq: error: ip1/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
ip1
jq: 1 compile error
```

From this you can see, I've determined various ways to join the separate files, but though I have code I thought would play into filtering, it's not correct / taking effect. Does anyone have an idea how to get the filter part working? TIA

Comment: Those keys don't match, thats intended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This assumes you are trying to combine the `.indices` object stored in `ie1.json` with an object within the object stored in `ip1.json`. As the keys upon to match are different, I further assumed that you want to match the field name from the `.indices` object, reduced by cutting off everything that comes after the last dash `-`, to the same key in the object from `ip1.json`.

To this end, `ip1.json` is read in from `input` as `$ip` (alternatively you can use `jq --argfile ip ip1.json` for that), then the `.indices` object is taken from the first input `ie1.json` and to the inner object accessed via `with_entries(.value …)` is added the result of a lookup within `$ip` at the matching and accordingly reduced `.key`.

```sh
jq '
  input as $ip | .indices | with_entries(.value += $ip[.key | sub("-[^-]*$";"")])
' ie1.json ip1.json
```

```json
{
  ".siem-signals-default-000001": {
    "action": "complete",
    "index": ".siem-signals-default-000001",
    "policy": ".siem-signals-default",
    "modified_date": "siem",
    "version": 1
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/jzGYJIHzc4)

If instead of the `.indices` object's inner field nane you want to have the content of field `.index` as reference (which in your sample data has the same value), you can go with `map_values` instead of `with_entries` as you don't need the field's name anymore.

```sh
jq '
  input as $ip | .indices | map_values(. += $ip[.index | sub("-[^-]*$";"")])
'ie1.json ip1.json
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/D1PeKr0r-2)

Note: I used `sub` with a regex to manipulate the key name, which you can easily adjust to your liking if in reality it is more complicated. If, however, the pattern is infact as simple as cutting off after the last dash, then using `.[:rindex("-")]` instead will also get the job done.

Comment: Ah, yay! Thank you! This works perfect. I made that way more complicated than it needed to be. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I also received offline feedback of a simple "workable for my use case" but not exact answer:

```
$ jq '.indices | map(. * input[.policy])' ie1.json ip1.json
[
  {
    "action": "complete",
    "index": ".siem-signals-default-000001",
    "policy": ".siem-signals-default",
    "modified_date": "siem",
    "version": 1
  }
]
```

Posting in case someone runs into similar, but other answer's better.